# How to execute a command only after the previous one has finished in a Server/Client program using sockets

Tags: c, linux, sockets, select, server

I'm making a client/server program in C using sockets. The server must be able to handle many clients.

After the server has been properly set up, the client connects to it, and sends either "Ready" or "Kill". The server receives the message, and reply back "Go" or "Destroy".

If the reply received by the client is "Go", then it executes a command passed in parameter. That command is executed like this : system(command)

If the reply received by the client is "Destroy", then the Client is closed, and the server is destroyed.

The Server must be able to handle many clients, BUT it must allow for only one client to execute a command at a time. Also, if a Client connects to the Server and sends "Kill", then all the Clients in the queue must be closed, and the Server must be Destroyed right away.

So, to achieve that, I'm using select()

So I'm having issues with this specification : it must allow for only one client to execute a command at a time.

Basically, the command is executed on the client side. And I don't want two Clients to be able to execute a command at the same time.

Here's an example (this is not code) :

```
Client1 : system(echosleep hello1 goodbye1);

Client2 : system(echosleep hello2 goodbye2);
```

So the way my program works right now, it prints :

```
hello1
hello2
goodbye1
goodbye2
```

But what I want is :

```
hello1
goodbye1
hello2
goodbye2
```

--> And I don't understand how the server could know if the command is finished or not, since it's executed on the Client side.

So here's my Server code structure (I am not posting the full code here, because my issue is not about writing the code itself, but more about the structure, and where exactly I should send "Go" to the Client... so I have left out irrelevant code) :

```
//initialize all client_socket[] to 0
//Create master_socket
//bind() master_socket
//listen() master_socket

//accept the incoming connection 
addrlen = sizeof(address);

while(TRUE) {
    //clear the socket set
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);

    //add master socket to set
    FD_SET(master_socket, &readfds);
    max_sd = master_socket;

    //add child sockets to set
    for ( i = 0 ; i < max_clients ; i++) {
        //socket descriptor
        sd = client_socket[i];

        //if valid socket descriptor then add to read list
        if(sd > 0) {
            FD_SET( sd , &readfds);
        }

        //highest file descriptor number, need it for the select function
        if(sd > max_sd) {
            max_sd = sd;
        }
    }

    //wait for an activity on one of the sockets , timeout is NULL , so wait indefinitely
    activity = select( max_sd + 1 , &readfds , NULL , NULL , NULL);

    if (activity < 0) {
        printf("select()");
    }

    //If something happened on the master socket , then its an incoming connection
    if (FD_ISSET(master_socket, &readfds)) {
        if ((new_socket = accept(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0) {
            perror("accept()");
            return -1;
        }

        //Check message received from the Client
        //if message == Kill then destroy everything   (this is working)

        //if message == Ready, then send Go
        //When the Client receives Go, it will proceed with the execution of his command

        //add Client to the queue
        for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++) {
            //if position is empty
            if( client_socket[i] == 0 ) {
                client_socket[i] = new_socket;              
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand how the server could know if the command is
>   finished or not

The simple answer is, it can't, for exactly the reason you mentioned.  The server has no way of knowing what is going on inside the client unless the client tells it.

Therefore, one solution to the problem would be to have the client send another message (e.g. "Done") back to the server after the client has finished executing the command.  Upon receiving the "Done" message, the server would know that the client was done executing and could then authorize another command on another client, if it wants to.

(btw having a client receive a string from the network and pass that string to system() is a big potential security hole -- an 'evil' server could pass a string like "rm -rf *" and cause your client to delete all its files!  So be careful when running your client software outside of an academic context)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Actually, I'm only sending the first letter (R for ready, etc.) I wrote the full words in my question because I thought it would simplify the problem. But it's good to know it could actually cause security issues. As for sending another message like "Done" it is a good idea, but I'm not allowed , in my assignment, to add any other message. I was hoping for a solution like using maybe the PID or something like that. But looks like it wont be possible.

Comment: I guess one other detail I failed to mention is that only one Client should be active at a time. That's why the next Client should only start after the previous one has finished. So I don't know if there would be a way to know if a Client is still active.

Comment: (sorry, forgot to tag you) @Jeremy

Comment: The server can detect when the client's TCP connection has closed (recv() will return 0 to indicate a closed TCP connection), so that's one way to detect if the client is no longer active (at least for some definitions of "active")

Comment: I think that could work. But I have more than 1 client connected at a time, so will recv() return 0 when all the clients are closed, or as soon as one client closes ? (After some tests, I think it will only return 0 when all the clients are closed) @Jeremy

Comment: Actually, the server is already sending a reply to the Client. I guess send() would return -1 when the client is closed. So I did this : `while(send(--arguments--) != -1){};`    And it seems to be working. Thanks !

Comment: recv() will return zero when the TCP connection associated with (the socket passed into that particular recv() call) is closed.